# Why is my java function not working with my test case I have tried everything

Tags: java, linked-list

this is my method public static LList subtract(LList list1, LList list2) {

```
    // Check if list1 is smaller than list2 based on lengths
    if (list1.length() < list2.length()) {
        // Swap list1 and list2
        LList temp = list1;
        list1 = list2;
        list2 = temp;
    } else if (list1.length() == list2.length()) {
        // If lengths are equal, iterate through the lists to find the greater number
        list1.moveToStart();
        list2.moveToStart();

        while (list1.currPos() < list1.length()) {
            int digit1 = (int) list1.getValue();
            int digit2 = (int) list2.getValue();
            if (digit1 < digit2) {
                // Swap list1 and list2
                LList temp = list1;
                list1 = list2;
                list2 = temp;
            } else if (digit1 > digit2) {
                // list1 is greater, no need to swap
                break; // No need to continue checking
            }
            list1.next();
            list2.next();
        }
    }
    // Check if list1 is longer than list2
    if (list1.length() > list2.length()) {
        // Calculate the difference in length between list1 and list2
        int lengthDifference = list1.length() - list2.length();
        // Pad list2 with leading zeros to match the length of list1
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthDifference; i++) {
            list2.append(0);
        }
    } else {
        // Calculate the difference in length between list2 and list1
        int lengthDifference = list2.length() - list1.length();
        // Pad list1 with leading zeros to match the length of list2
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthDifference; i++) {
            list1.append(0);
        }
    }
    list1.moveToStart();
    list2.moveToStart();
    LList finalResult = new LList();
    int borrow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length(); i++) {
        int digit1 = (int) list1.getValue();
        int digit2 = (int) list2.getValue() + borrow;
        if (digit1 < digit2) {
            borrow = 1;
            digit1 += 10;
        } else {
            borrow = 0;
        }
        int currentDifference = digit1 - digit2;
        finalResult.append(currentDifference);
        list1.next();
        list2.next();
    }

    return finalResult;
}
```

this is my test cases
`LList num1 = new LList();
LList num2 = new LList();
LList result = new LList();

```
    num1 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("1279");
     num2 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("523");
     result = BigNumArithmetic.subtract(num1, num2);
    assertEquals("756", BigNumArithmetic.listToString(result), "Subtraction of positive num

    // Test subtraction with leading zeros
    num1 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("1005");
    num2 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("509");
    result = BigNumArithmetic.subtract(num1, num2);
    assertEquals("496", BigNumArithmetic.listToString(result), "Subtraction with leading z

    // Test subtraction with unequal lengths
    num1 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("12345");
    num2 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("678");
    result = BigNumArithmetic.subtract(num1, num2);
    assertEquals("11667", BigNumArithmetic.listToString(result), "Subtraction witlengths");

    // Test subtraction with borrow
    num1 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("856");
    num2 = BigNumArithmetic.stringToList("900");
    result = BigNumArithmetic.subtract(num1, num2);
    assertEquals("44", BigNumArithmetic.listToString(result), "Subtraction with borrow");
}`
```

Ive tried changing list1.movetoend but that doesnt work and I have tried many different things to try and fix this but I cannot find one thing that works. I am subtracting two linked lists that have integers in them and cannot have a negative number.